# Maxima and/or minima of $a_n = \frac{e^{n!\tan (n\pi)}-1+n^2\sin n}{\log (1+3^{n\log n})\log (n+5^n)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, logarithms

$$a_n = \frac{e^{n!\tan (n\pi)}-1+n^2\sin n}{\log (1+3^{n\log n})\log (n+5^n)}, n \in \mathbb{N}$$

This sequence:

1. Has minimum but no maximum
2. Has neither maximum nor minimum
3. Has both maximum and minimum
4. Has maximum but no minimum

I have tried by looking at the limit of this sequence, and since $\tan(n\pi) = 0$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, the $e^{\tan \pi}$ seems to be constantly equal to 1. The two logarithms at the denominator approach $+\infty$, but the numerator doesn't seem to approach a number due to the sine.

$a_1 = \frac{\sin 1}{\log 2 \log 6}$, however that's not enough for me to draw any conclusions on maxima and/or minima without being able to evaluate the limit.

This kind of exercise is the one I tend to have the most problems with. When I have to determine whether there is an upper/lower bond, or maxima/minima I tend to struggle the most with it.

Any hints?

Comment: Argue that $|a_n| \to 0$ (hint: $\log$ is a monotone function, and $|\sin| \le 1$). Since $a_1 > 0$ and $a_4 < 0$ clearly hold, this is enough to show that both maxima and minima exist, since we can find some $N$ such that for $n >N$ $|a_n| < \min( |a_1|, |a_4|) \implies a_4 < a_n < a_1$, and so the extrema must be attained before $N$.

Comment: You are the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$e^{n!\tan (n\pi)}$ will be exactly equal to $1$ for all integral values since $\tan n\pi$ is exactly equal to $0$. Hence, the fraction becomes $\frac{n^2\sin n}{\ln (1+3^{n\ln n})\ln (n+5^n)}$.
$\implies L=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin n}{\frac{\ln(1+3^{n\ln n})}{n}\frac{\ln(n+5^n)}{n}}$

For any integral value of $n, \sin n$ does not vanish and oscillates between $(-1,1)$. For the denominator, both separate factors can be resolved using L'Hospital's Rule.

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(1+3^{n\ln n})}{n}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{1+3^{n\ln n}}\cdot3^{n\ln n}\cdot(1+\ln n)\ln3}{1}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\ln3(1+\ln n)\to\infty$
Similarly, the other factor tends to a finite value. Hence, the denominator tends to $\infty$ and $L\to0$.

Therefore, the sequence converges to $0$.

Comment: But the correct answer is that it has both maximum and minimum

Comment: @SamueleB. The measure of angle is in radians, right? That is the only thing I can think of that can bound the sequence.

Comment: Yes it's radians. Unfortunately, there is no explanation on the paper that reports the correct answers, it just says that there are both maximum and minimum.

Comment: Your error here is that $\log(1 + 3^{n\log n}) \neq n\log(n) \log 3 \times \log (1 + 3^{-n\log n})$ but is instead $n\log(n) \log (3) \mathbf{+} \log (1 + 3^{-n\log n})$ (similarly for the other term). In fact, $|a_n| \to 0$ as $n$ blows up.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Thanks for pointing that out. I will correct it.